# Saving data in Angular using localstorage

Tags: angular, mobile, storage

I'm trying to store data on a mobile phone. I use Angular and I think to store it on Local Storage but it looks like it have a limit of capacity. Another option is that I write the data to a file and read the data into my application but I don't know if that is possible on a mobile phone. Do you suggest any of these or do you recommend other options (sqlite, etc).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: what kind of data you are trying to save ?

Comment: I'm making an event calendar. I want to save events offline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your event object to a string then store them in Localstorage,
Unless your project have a binary files then I believe Localstorage is more than enough,
This example is using a caching service to store the http requests, you absolutely can do the same.
https://dev.to/mauro_codes/client-side-caching-with-angular-2i6l

Comment: Do you have any idea how much events it can store? An event has a name, start- and endtime so I don't know how much I can store in localstorage.

Comment: I do not think there is a limit for such small data as yours
the example is explained in the URL above

Answer (score 0):

Checkout IndexedDB. This is not related to Angular, it is a broader frontend topic.

Ref https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API